# Are double rolls added when you land on the utilities?

Tags: monopoly

If you own both utilities and your opponent throws 1/2/3 doubles do they pay 10 times the total on all the throws or just the last throw.

Answer (score 8):

Just the last throw, as shown on the deed card:

> If one "Utility" is owned rent is 4 times amount shown on dice. If both "Utilities" are owned rent is 10 times amount shown on dice.

"amount shown on dice", not "amount of all rolls this turn."

This is further reinforced on the [Wiki](https://monopoly.fandom.com/wiki/Electric_Company):

> If ONE Utility is owned, rent is 4x the number on the dice which landed the player on the utility, but if BOTH Utilities are owned, rent is 10x the amount shown on the dice.

(and with the analysis that the rent paid if both are owned averages to $70 , also given on that wiki page).

Comment: Exception : If your last throw landed you on a Chance square, and the card directed you to  "Advance token to nearest utility", the last throw of the dice is meaningless. The card will direct you to"... throw dice [again] and pay [the] owner 10 times the amount thrown.", regardless if the owner owns one or both utilities.

Comment: Well, that's clear, sure. One needn't include "If a game effect gives explicit overriding instructions, those instructions take precedence." with every answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is not in [the rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/monins.pdf). But on [this page](https://monopoly.fandom.com/wiki/Utility):

> Utilities are the only properties without fixed rents, as rent depends
>   on **the dice roll** which landed the token on the property.

They only mention the dice roll, that landed the token on the property. So the rolls are not added.